# Detect Shapes, Images, and Mouse Overflowing from HTML Canvas with console.log(); (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am testing the HTML `<canvas></canvas>` tags to create a vanilla JavaScript game for [Games4Change](http://www.gamesforchange.org/studentchallenge/nyc/inclusive-play/#1570646883477-df83cb23-4a76a09a-1d3b53e5-e69d) inside my website.

As I was testing the width and height of the canvas with a `ctx.fillRect(955, 0, 5, 5);`, I was wondering how I could detect JavaScript shapes using `console.log();`, as their stroke/border overflows or goes out of the bounds of the HTML `<canvas></canvas>` border.

Furthermore, I am wondering how I could make JavaScript detect images and their borders overflowing through the HTML `<canvas></canvas>` border using `console.log();` since I will be switching to images for my game instead of shapes.

Also, how do you make Javascript detect if the mouse cursor is out of the HTML `<canvas></canvas>` border using `console.log();`?

**HTML**

```
<canvas class="center" id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
#gameCanvas {
    width: 960px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(52,52,52,1.00);/**
    background-color: rgba(241,213,179,1.00);**/
}
```

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```
//Gets the html canvas that displays the game and allows art/rendering of the game in 2 dimensional plane.
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Determine the size the canvas is being displayed
   var width = canvas.clientWidth;
   var height = canvas.clientHeight;


console.log(canvas.clientWidth);
console.log(canvas.clientHeight);


//Clears all content everytime the game is reloaded by frame of the rectangular screen.
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 960, 480);

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(955, 0, 5, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after declaring canvas:

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", console.log("mouse out"), false);
```

is all you need to know the mouse was over the canvas and then left.

for defining objects inside your canvas element it is a little more tricky, but essentially you need something that is keeping track of that object's width and height location (like x and y coordinates). then, you can check if that location is outside your hard-defined canvas size, for example:

```js
if ((location.x < 0 || location.x > 960) || (location.y < 0 || location.y > 480)) {
console.log("i am outside");
}
```

instead of 0 and 960, of course, you can make that area smaller to account for the size of the object, so instead it logs "i am outside" when even an edge or corner exits the canvas.

i would suggest checking out something like vector.js to start defining location and movement for game objects.